# Camera in Raspberry Pi shows no input on screen

Tags: camera, ubuntu, raspi-config

I am new to using Raspberry Pi. I have RSP 4 model B, I need it for a college project I am doing, I bought a camera module  for it.
and it doesn't show output on screen using "cheese"
I am running Ubuntu 20.10(64 bit). It does show the camera output
I disconnected it and connected again and found it's name is "mmal service 16.1" (so the system recognizes it).
I think I need to initialize it.
A lot of posts talk about `raspi-config`, but I can't use it on my OS as far as I have seen.
also I had no `boot/config.txt` file I put it there manually with the configuration:

```
gpu_mem=128
disable_camera_led=1
start_file=start_x.elf
fixup_file=fixup_x.dat
```

and restarted.
also used the commands `sudo get-apt update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade` still black input.
Also I did remove the camera cover.

Edit: I messed up the configuration and the Raspberry Pi wasn't booting anymore, so I installed the Raspberry Pi native OS instead, so this question is no longer valid.